# Composite data type with an array field

Tags: julia

How do I declare an array field with a fixed size inside a data type?
I'm creating a composite data type called CPU. I understand you can set the type of the field as an array type but can you instantiate the size as well or do I need to make an explicit constructor?

```
type CPU
      //how do I declare memory as an Int8 array of size 64K
//memory::Array{Int8,1}
//memory = Array{Int8,64000}?   
  OpCode::Int8
  Operand::Int8
  Condition::Int8
  PC::Int64
end
```

Comment: I would recommend asking a separate question on this.  Chris already did a good job, in my opinion, answering the first question you posed.  This revision is now rather different.  It will be more useful for future users of the site if the two questions are separate, and also nicer to the people who answer questions if the questions don't become moving targets.

Comment: Hi @JJTO, welcome to Stack Overflow! I rolled back your question to your first revision. Please ask the new question separately, as this would be more helpful to other users who have similar questions.

Comment: You can retrieve what you wrote in your revision (for the purposes of moving it to a new question) by clicking on the "edited x amount of time ago" link at the bottom of your question.  Click on the "side by side" link to see the full text of what the post was before Fengyang's rollback.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An array type doesn't have a size parameter. The type for memory would be `Vector{Int8}` (or `Array{Int8,1}`, `Vector` is just an alias for a 1-dimensional array). You could use an inner constructor to check the size or throw an error.

For even more safety, you could create a new type which just has an array and defines dispatches for `length`, `getindex`, etc., to make an array interface to the array it holds, but doesn't define the methods to resize. This is probably overkill (and if you grab the field that is the array, you could still resize it).

FixedSizeArrays or StaticArrays are not applicable here since the array is too large (they would increase compile time by a lot).

Comment: yes, I used an inner constructor like you suggested and it works. Thanks for the help. But I'm still having trouble understanding what you mean in the second paragraph... are you saying I create a new constructor for just the array type with length as one of the argument? But I thought you cant instantiate an array with fixed size in a Type?  Sorry, I'm still thinking in terms of C/C++ where you can easily create a struct with an arbitrary length array so I just can't get my head around why in Julia, you can't do the same.

Comment: If you use `Array{Int8,1}` as a field, then it's a type with an arbitrary length array, so I don't see what you mean. What I am saying in the second paragraph is that, if you don't like that arrays have a `resize!` function, you can define an immutable type with one field which is an array, and define the behavior for this new array by defining all of the array functions yourself (i.e. make `length` calculate the length of the array that is the only field, etc.). This new array type won't have any overhead, but this is overkill

Comment: If what you mean is that you want to declare the memory along with the type, note that the field for an array holds a pointer to the array, not the array itself. You wouldn't want to declare memory for the array in the type anyways because in order to define the type you will have already had to define the array, and so having two definitions would make you do an extra copy (so it's better for the type to just point to the same piece of memory). Is that what you're asking about?